# Type of engine 2004 Ford Excursion V10

Tags: engine, ford, interference, excursion

Is the engine on 2004 Ford Excursion V10 an interference engine?

Comment: Most modern engines are interference.  Why do you ask?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Answer (score 2):

According to [this forum post](https://www.ford-trucks.com/forums/976838-6-8l-info-needed.html#post9147389), the Ford Triton V10 is an interference engine. I saw a bunch of other references out there stating the same.